# Error in complete.cases(y) : invalid 'type' (closure) of argument

Tags: r

I have the data which has data$var1 values which varies in between from `-39 to +29`

I am trying to run:

```
library(rdrobust)
with(data, rdplot(y = n, p=1, x = data$var1, c=0, nbins=35,
title="title1",
x.label="label1", y.label="label2"))
```

I am getting the following error

> Error in complete.cases(y) : invalid 'type' (closure) of argument

I could not figure out the problem. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is `n` a column in _data_ i.e. for `y=n` make sure `n` is a column in _data_

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Please give a [mre] in your question!